# automatic subtract words when page resized or zoomed

Tags: php, html

i would like to know how can i make my title in divs automatically substracted to a certain number to stay fitting the div when resizing window or zooming website as [youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9_XeX_-TJ0) do ?

im substracting words like that

```
   $string = (strlen($title) > 13) ? substr($title,0,26).'..' : $title;

   echo "<div>";
   echo $string;
   echo "</div>;
```

But i dont know how to do this automatically so it can substract more letters to fit the div.

now what i have is when page resized or zoomed the title stay long and will out of the div.

how can i fix this with php or javascript thanks. i tried looking how youtube doing it but no luck.

Comment: WHAT ABOUT css overflow?

Comment: i want automatically substract letters only. i have list a videos like youtube.

Comment: this would require js, it can't be done with php

Comment: what about text-overflow:ellipsis ?

Comment: @Mangiucugna didnt help.

Comment: very strange, if you could post a fiddle with your markup and js I'll be very happy to debug :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS3 text-overflow: ellipsis like this:

```
<div style="text-overflow: ellipsis;width:5%;overflow: hidden">
     Some text
</div>
```

Try with the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bBTaU/ 
Resize the window and see

EDIT

Not all browsers support CSS3, you can use a plugin like this http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/ to extend the support in old browser